# Replicate Wireshark Capture of 802.11 QoS Packet in Scapy

Tags: wireshark, scapy, wifi

I have captured some WLAN `802.11 QoS` packets using `Wireshark` and I am trying to replicate same packets using `Scapy`

Here goes the screenshot of the captured packet. Please let me know if more screenshots will help.

[image: Wireshark capture of 802.11 QoS Packet]

Here is the `scapy` commands I used to generate a packet with 4 bytes of dummy data.

```
dot11=Dot11(type=2, subtype=8, addr1='11:11:11:11:11:11', addr2='22:22:22:22:22:22', addr3='33:33:33:33:33:33')
frame = RadioTap()/dot11/Dot11QoS()/"abcd"
```

If I use Wireshark to look into the packet using `wireshark(frame)` command, it identifies the packet as `802.11 QoS` packet. But just above the `Data` field, it shows a `Logical Link Control` field.

On the other hand, if I send the packet on the interface using `sendp(frame, iface='wlan0')`, wireshark will capture the packet as `LLC` packet. My question is why same packet is shown differently in two different case?

Also my idea is to replicate exactly same packet to send it to an `IoT` device and get the response. Is it possible to forge packets for that? If it is possible, what am I missing to generate same packet using `scapy`?

Answer (score 0):

To replicate packets, the easiest way would be to directly sniff them on Scapy. The *sniff* function does just that: it have two main parameters, *filter* and *prn*.

*filter* specifies which packets to capture according to the [BPF syntax](http://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html).

*prn* specifies which function to apply to the filtered packets.

For example:

```
def f(pkt):
    pkt.show()
filt="src host 1.2.3.4"
sniff(prn=f,filter=filt)
```

This code will capture all packets coming from the machine having the IP address *1.2.3.4* and will show their fields.

But if you absolutely want to do the sniffing via Wireshark, you can check that you replicate all the fields thanks to the scapy *ls* function that displays all the field names of a layer constructor:

```
>>> ls(ARP)
sport
dport
len
chksum
```

Good luck in whatever you're trying to do